# With Rails 5, how to think about naming a form field to later be used be a Rails Controller#create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5, I have the following model:

**Talents.rb**

```
id | Title
1 | Jumping
2 | Skipping
3 | Running
```

My API, returns Talents#Index like so:

```
[
 {"id":1,"title":"Jumping"},
 {"id":2,"title":"Skipping Rope"},
 {"id":3,"title":"Running"},
 {"id":4,"title":"Something Else"}
]
```

I then want to use the respond to build a form:

```
<div>
   <label>Jumping</label>
   <select name="Jumping">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">XXX</option>
      <option value="2">YYY</option>
   </select>
</div>
....
```

My question is how should I be thinking about NAMING the talents in the form so that I can properly post the form to Rails to then record the user's response?

Do I need another field from the API with some type of Key? Or for select name, should I be using the ID?

Comment: You mean to build a select dropdowns with title as in the response?

Comment: The <div> example is for just one of the items in the API response (as an example)... I mean when building that HTML form object, what to use as the NAME, so that I post to Rails in a way where rails can create the record... Should the SELECT NAME be title? or id? or something else? thanks

Comment: Ok. I got it. Select name will be title from the response

Comment: You "must" use the names according to the params you're expecting to receive @AnApprentice, params defined in your controllers.

Comment: But you have many titles!

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Not sure! Also to be honest didnt understood the question fully :)

Comment: exactly! that's where I'm confused.. titles are not necessarily unique. so then for SELECT NAME should I be using the ID? And if I am to use the ID, how does the Rails Controller#create know what to do with just an ID?

Comment: As Sebastián already pointed out, you should first define how you will use that data, then you will know the best way to format that data (and thus, define the `select` box `name`) before sending it to your controller. How will you save the data with your controller?

Comment: @Gerry these go hand in hand, I'm not sure the best way to send/save the data to the controller.

Comment: I see, so lets go deeper; how will your model store the data (i.e. what's the table structure)?

Comment: @Gerry the model would be Rating (id, user_id, rated_by, talent_id, rating (integer) ... does this help?

Comment: I current have the following being posted to my API: `{"talent_id_6"=>"4", "talent_id_7"=>"4", "talent_id_9"=>"3"}` and I'm thinking in the Rails controller I can loop over all the params and somehow parse the key w `talent_id_` --- it feels really sloppy.. thoughts?

Comment: So i assume that the `value` in each `option` represents a `rating`, correct? If so, do you set `user_id` and `rated_by` somewhere else? or it should also be part of the data that the `form` will send?

Comment: correct: "the value in each option represents a rating"

Comment: user_id and rated_by will be set outside of the form, not struggling to figure out how to send these two fields.

Comment: @Gerry any ideas?

Comment: @AnApprentice Check the answer, if i understood correctly, that will work for what you are trying to do. Also, try updating your question with the relevant information from this comments.

Comment: That is genius. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do something like this:

```
<form name="my-form" method="post" action="/create">
  <div>
    <label>Jumping</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="ratings[]talent_id" value="1"></input>
    <select name="ratings[]rating">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Rating 1</option>
      <option value="2">Rating 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Skipping</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="ratings[]talent_id" value="2"></input>
    <select name="ratings[]rating">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Rating 1</option>
      <option value="2">Rating 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Running</label>
    <input type="hidden" name="ratings[]talent_id" value="3"></input>
    <select name="ratings[]rating">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Rating 1</option>
      <option value="2">Rating 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

- Using `ratings[]` will create an array, which enables you tu use **the same name** for each `select`.
- Adding an `input` with type `hidden`, will allow to specify which talent is being rated (the value of each `input` is the `talent_id` to be rated in that `select`).

For example, if a user selects the following:

- `Rating 2` for `Jumper`
- `Rating 1` for `Jumping`
- `Rating 1` for `Skipping`

Then the following parameters will be sent to your controller:

```
Parameters: {
  "ratings"=>[
    {"talent_id"=>"1", "rating"=>"2"},
    {"talent_id"=>"2", "rating"=>"1"},
    {"talent_id"=>"3", "rating"=>"1"}
  ]
}
```

Now, in your controller you could just iterate over `params[:ratings]` to create each object, maybe something like this:

```
params[:ratings].each do |rating|
  rating_attributes = {
    user_id: user,                 # use the appropriate `user_id`
    rated_by: rater,               # use the appropriate `rated_by`
    talent_id: rating[:talent_id],
    rating: rating[:rating]
  }

  Rating.create!(rating_attributes)
end
```

Of course you should optimize this method by, for example, handling errors instead of raising an exception (as `create!` does); but this will get you going.

Comment: You nailed it!!